# sudo command not working in startup-script

Tags: linux, node.js, debian, google-compute-engine, sudo

This is a part of the startup script for my compute engine instance

```
# Configure supervisor to run the node app.
cat >/etc/supervisor/conf.d/node-app.conf << EOF
[program:nodeapp]
directory=/opt/app
command=sudo node app.js
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=nodeapp
environment=HOME="/home/nodeapp",USER="nodeapp",NODE_ENV="production"
stdout_logfile=syslog
stderr_logfile=syslog
EOF
```

If you notice this line

```
command=sudo node app.js
```

originally it was just

```
command=node app.js
```

but since my app is listening on port 80, I modified it so I could have root access. When my virtual machine starts up, it executes the script but I can't access my website, when I SSH into the instance and type

```
sudo node app.js
```

however, everything works. You can't have sudo commands in the startup script?

Comment: Why is `supervisord` not running as root?  What user *is* it running as?  Is that the same user you were using when you ran `sudo node app.js` successfully?   Does your `sudo` configuration have  the `requiretty` option set?

Comment: how would I run supervisord as root? What is the requiretty option? This is code from the "deploy nodejs app on google compute engine" tutorial. I don't understand it completely.

Comment: should I add the entire startup script?

Comment: It should be sufficient to change `user=nodeapp` to `user=root` and it will start as root because `supervisord` is already running as root. Keep the `command=node app.js` without `sudo`.

Comment: @alvits perfect. thnx

Answer (score 0):

First you have to [grant sudo access](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_OpenStack_Platform/2/html/Getting_Started_Guide/ch02s03.html) to `nodeapp` user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Node as `root` anyway (which is the effect of using `sudo`), you might as well set `user=root` (or remove that setting entirely) and keep the original `command`.